# How to synchronize token(string value) between application nodes?

Tags: token, nodes, synchronization

We have a Spring 3 + REST application in which we are using a token to identify source of request coming in. This token is kept in-memory(in a hashmap) and used to identify the request.
When we are multiple instance of our app(deployed on multiple tomcat instances on different machines), how can we share/sync this token between different app nodes?
Our only requirement is to sync this token among different nodes.

I browsed and found few apis'/software like Redis, memcached, zookeeper. I am not able to decide which one to select.

Any kind of suggestion/comments is helpful.

Regards,
Pramod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used zookeeper so I cannot say anything about it. Both Redis (database) and memcached (cache) will work for you. Which one is better depends on how you use tokens.

Choose Redis if:

- tokens may be stored for a long time
- no need to expire tokens
- want to handle more tokens than can be stored in memory
- want to replicate tokens to other servers so if one goes down other will provide tokens
- tokens have to survive server restart

Choose memcached if:

- tokens are valid only for certain amount of time and should expire
- amount of tokens exeed memory capacity the least recently used token will be removed
- all tokens may be stored in memory
- no need to replicate tokens to other server
- tokens don't have to survive server restart
- want to use Spring Cache abstraction

Comment: Thanks ragnor, looks like memcached looks relevant in my case.
what is difference between spymemcached and simple-spring-memcached?

Comment: But, one problem is that tokens need to be synchronized between tomcat nodes running the same application(distributed synchronization). what should I go with? How about Apache JCS?

Comment: You should set up dedicated server (redis or memcached) that will be used by all tomcats instances. Is such case redis/memcached will be a single resource shared by all tomcats servers. Spymemcached is a java client for memcached with standard set of operations: set, get, delete, multiget etc. Simple-spring-memcached uses spymemcached (or xmemcached) and enables caching in you application using simple annotations on your methods. I think you should start with spymemcached and see if it works for you.

Comment: hi @ragnor, as memcached does not support replication I like to try out Redis. I tried to download Redis, but did not find setup for Windows system. Can you provide me address from where I can download Redis for Windows 2008 server?

Comment: There is no official version of Redis on Windows, you may try this unofficial: https://github.com/dmajkic/redis/

Comment: hi @ragnor, is there a way to replicate tokens between various memcached servers? becoz even if one goes down then data stored on it should be available from other instances. Redis is out of question as no prod quality windows setup is available. Can you suggest any other other tool?

Comment: Memcached is also not available on Windows, there are some unofficial versions but I won't use them on production. You should set up a few linux boxes to run Redis or memcached. I've never used Windows as a production/deployment environment.

Comment: hi Ragnor, I was looking at Apache JCS, that does not require any separate installation, just couple of jar file to get started. Your thoughts on this?

Comment: I've never used Apache JCS